# Who is William?

Tags: riddle, poetry

Meadow of visions
The tranquility of young sheep
The pious, the wretched, and the unsightly
Pirates of the misplaced vessel
Liberate William

Comment: This worked better on Facebook, posted without context. Reading aunts’ and uncles’ and cousins’ “interpretations” was a great entertainment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He's a

> Whale, as they're all film titles

Meadow of visions

> Field of dreams

The tranquility of young sheep

> Silence of the lambs

The pious, the wretched, and the unsightly

> The good, the bad, and the ugly

Pirates of the misplaced vessel

> Raiders of the lost ark

Liberate William

> Free Willy

Comment: rot13(xvyyre junyr) to be accurate

Comment: Weirdly, I was about to go with that and then second guessed myself for some reason.